# Bootstrap - Vertically Align Icon in List

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this page, I need to vertically align an icon within an inline list. This icon is within a circle. So really, I want the entire circle vertically aligned. I have a Bootply setup [here](http://www.bootply.com/B4SRNNyGFb). In this Bootply, I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><div class="circle text-center"><i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size:18px; padding-top:6px;"></i></div></li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.example.com" style="font-size:16px;">Some Page</a>
        <div style="font-size:14px;">A longer line of test that describes the link</div>
      </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I vertically center the content in the first `li` relative to the content in the second `li`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.list-inline>li {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/BxgnmdnKZt

Also, you may want to consider using the `media` object instead..

```
    <ul class="media">
      <li class="media-left media-middle"><div class="circle text-center"><i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size:18px; padding-top:6px;"></i></div></li>
      <li class="media-right">
        <a href="https://www.example.com" style="font-size:16px;">Some Page</a>
        <div style="font-size:14px;">A longer line of test that describes the link</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

http://www.bootply.com/pR9JHBBSAE